# QuickFIX python connection error:Timed out waiting for logon response

Tags: python, tcp, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

i get timed out error while running the Quickfix application in python. here i add a console response.i did not get a logon response

```
<20190306-11:00:08.000000000, FIX.4.2:TW->ISLD, event>
  (Created session)
<20190306-11:00:08.000000000, FIX.4.2:TW->ISLD, event>
  (Connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 50182 (Source :0))
<20190306-11:00:08.000000000, FIX.4.2:TW->ISLD, outgoing>
  (8=FIX.4.29=6735=A34=149=TW52=20190306- 
11:00:08.00056=ISLD98=0108=30141=Y10=244)
<20190306-11:00:08.000000000, FIX.4.2:TW->ISLD, event>
  (Initiated logon request)
<20190306-11:00:58.000000000, FIX.4.2:TW->ISLD, event>
  (Timed out waiting for logon response)
<20190306-11:00:58.000000000, FIX.4.2:TW->ISLD, event>
  (Disconnecting)
```

and my configuration file is

```
# default settings for sessions
[DEFAULT]
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=TW



[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y

TargetCompID=ISLD
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=50182
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
DataDictionary=/Volumes/Untitled2/python_projects/FIX_api/spec/fix/FIX42.xml
LogonTimeout=50
CheckLatency = Y
MaxLatency = 120
```

Comment: Does a telnet test succeed?  Looks like your counterparty is down or your network is blocked.

Comment: what was the cause of this issue?